# Set condition to coloured table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set orange background of table B only if CURRENT DATE - FIRST is equal or more than 14 days.

I tried this in formatting rules

[image]

```
="IF(($H$3-$C3)>=14); ;)"
```

I have problem how to set if condition.

Thanks for answer and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should work: =IF($H$3-$C3>=14;TRUE;FALSE)

If your issue is with vba then you must define your condition like this:

```
myRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IF($H$3-$C3>=14;TRUE;FALSE)"
```